# LINQ to Entities - Skip & Take hang Sometimes and Delayed execution

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem about Skip-Take. I am working on WPF Application and i have the table that in the future it will contain a large number of data. For that reason I decided to paginate index view.

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2, and the problem occurs when run the application and open the view that display the data. Some times it takes 25 seconds to display data.

After debug many times, the line that delayed execution was detected, it is the line that execute query.

The code as below :

```
        IQueryable<TResult> items = _context.Items
                                     .AsNoTracking()
                                     .Include(b => b.Category)
                                     .Where(predicate ?? (p => true))
                                     .OrderBy(i => i.Name)
                                     .Select(target);


        var total = await items.CountAsync();

        var results = new Paginated<TResult>
            (
            data: items.Skip((model.PageSize - 1) * model.PageSize)
                      .Take(model.PageSize)
                      .ToList(),
            total: total
            );


        return results;
```

I hope to get a solution to this strange problem to improve performance.

Thanks in advance  .

**Edite**
The sql query generated as :

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[BoxesBalaita], [t].[Boxescontainer20], [t].[Boxescontainer40], [t].[CategoryId], [t].[Country], [t].[Imagepath], [t].[IsDeleted], [t].[ItemNumber], [t].[MinimumQuantity], [t].[Name], [t].[Sizelevel], [t].[Tariff], [t].[Weightbox], [i.Category].[Id], [i.Category].[Name], [i.Category].[ParentId]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [i].[Id], [i].[BoxesBalaita], [i].[Boxescontainer20], [i].[Boxescontainer40], [i].[CategoryId], [i].[Country], [i].[Imagepath], [i].[IsDeleted], [i].[ItemNumber], [i].[MinimumQuantity], [i].[Name], [i].[Sizelevel], [i].[Tariff], [i].[Weightbox]
    FROM [Items] AS [i]
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [i.Category] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [i.Category].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
OFFSET @__p_1 ROWS',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=25,@__p_1=0
```

the Expression :

```
public static Expression<Func<Item, OutputModel>> Model => u => new OutputModel()
        {
            Id = u.Id,
            Name = u.Name,
            BoxesBalaita = u.BoxesBalaita,
            Boxescontainer20 = u.Boxescontainer20,
            Boxescontainer40 = u.Boxescontainer40,
            Country = u.Country,
            Imagepath = u.Imagepath,
            MinimumQuantity = u.MinimumQuantity,
            Sizelevel = u.Sizelevel,
            Tariff = u.Tariff,
            Weightbox = u.Weightbox,
            ItemNumber = u.ItemNumber,
            CategoryId = u.CategoryId,
            CategoryName = u.Category.Name

        };
```

Comment: Could you profile the data provider and post the SQL query that is executed when this line runs?

Comment: Problem might be migrations. If there are migrations and you drop and create database it will take time for sure. Other reason might be database is "sleeping" and it takes time to wake it up before it can return data. Both scenarios are about first request.

Comment: Can you please specify what your TResult type is in this case? (Is it an Entity, or a ViewModel?) If a Viewmodel, please include the definitions. Also, please include the "target" expression used in this case. To confirm, when debugging, the `var results = new Paginated....` line is taking the 25 seconds time to execute? How long does the Count line take, and what was the total returned?

Comment: @dropoutcoder    I did not understand you well, but the problem occurred with me in the first request and in the other request

Comment: @StevePy I modified the question and inserted expression into it , the total count is 10,000 rows , and data contains 25 objects .

Comment: Thanks, I'm guessing this is EF Core? my guess would be `ItemMeagerUnit = u.ItemMeasureUnits.ToModel()`. EF wouldn't be able to resolve `ToModel` where EF 6 would throw an exception, EF Core would materialize the query behind the scenes to continue processing. (a rather dumb feature to hide more performance issues) Try changing this to a `.Select()` to build the ItemMeagerUnit model in-line. I don't see the ItemMeasureunits mentioned in your posted SQL so I suspect these would be loaded in a followup query.

Comment: @StevePy I'am using EF Core 2.2 !!

Comment: I see you removed that line from your pasted example, are you still seeing query performance issues? Be wary of any reference to NotMapped/Ingore properties in the entitites because I believe EF Core will prematurely materialize to handle these as well.

Comment: @StevePy Yes , iremoved that line , but the issues is still

Comment: How long is the DbContext left alive in your application? What happens if you replace `_context` with `using (var context = new YourAppContext())`?